# How to use Aggregator to append Exchange Headers

Tags: java, spring-boot, apache-camel, append

I am writing an Aggregator Strategy class where I need headers of old exchange and new exchange should be appended to each other so that a collective header should be passed on to next processor class.

I tried `putAll` newHeader but it is not appending to the old exchange.

```
Map<String, Object> newHeader = newExchange.getIn().getHeaders();
oldExchange.getIn().getHeaders().putAll(newHeader);
return oldExchange;
```

Any suggestions? How can I achieve this?

Comment: Have you tried to set each header in a loop with `oldExchange.getIn().setHeader`?

Comment: I can, but I shouldn't as I am writing a generic class, I can't specify each header key. it has to be for all header present.

Comment: You don't need to specify the keys in a loop. Just iterate over the Header Map and use key and value from the current entry of the iteration.

Comment: This looks like it should work in principle.  Can you share the whole class?

Answer (score 0):

```
public class AggregateHeaders implements AggregationStrategy {
@Override
public Exchange aggregate(Exchange oldExchange, Exchange newExchange) {
    Map<String, Object> newHeaders = newExchange.getIn().getHeaders();
    oldExchange.getIn().getHeaders().putAll(newHeaders);
    return oldExchange;
}}
```

Your code should be working as expected...

Wrote a small test

```
@Test
public void test() {
    DefaultCamelContext context = new DefaultCamelContext();
    AggregateHeaders aggregator = new AggregateHeaders();
    DefaultExchange newExchange = new DefaultExchange(context);
    newExchange.getIn().setHeader("newName", "newValue");
    DefaultExchange oldExchange = new DefaultExchange(context);
    oldExchange.getIn().setHeader("oldName", "oldValue");
    Exchange aggregated = aggregator.aggregate(oldExchange, newExchange);
    assertThat(aggregated.getIn().getHeader("oldName"), is("oldValue"));
    assertThat(aggregated.getIn().getHeader("newName"), is("newValue"));
}
```

see also https://camel.apache.org/maven/current/camel-core/apidocs/org/apache/camel/Message.html#setHeaders(java.util.Map)

> Important: If you want to copy headers from another Message to this Message, then use **getHeaders().putAll(other)** to copy the headers, where other is the other headers.